# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' problem

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

The Errors looks like follows :

[image: Gradle code]

```
buildscript {
        ext {
            version_kotlin = "1.6.10"
            version_core = '1.7.0'
            version_constraint_layout = '2.1.3'
            version_lifecycle_extensions = "2.2.0"
            version_material = '1.5.0'
            version_navigation = '2.4.1'
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
    
            //noinspection JcenterRepositoryObsolete
            jcenter()
    
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version_kotlin"
            classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle- 
    plugin:$version_navigation"
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    ext {
        kotlinStdlibJdk7Version = '1.6.10'
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: What Android Gradle Plugin are you using and is it compatible with the gradle bin that you are using ?